# Remove a character from the end of a variable

Tags: bash, shell

Bash auto completion appends a / at the end of a directory name. How I can strip this off from a positional parameter?

```
#!/bin/sh

target=$1

function backup(){
  date=`date "+%y%m%d_%H%M%S"`
  PWD=`pwd`
  path=$PWD/$target
  tar czf /tmp/$date$target.tar.gz $path
}

backup
```

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Use

```
target=${1%/}
```

A [reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20161225192604/http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/bashref/ShellParameterExpansion.html).

Comment: And it is [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), so is pretty much portable.

Comment: See [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198045/how-to-strip-the-last-slash-of-the-directory-path) for a simple way to strip multiple trailing '/'s while keeping root (/) safe:  
  `case $x in
  *[!/]*/) x=${x%"${x##*[!/]}"};;
esac`

Comment: and if you had to use this with a variable, e.g. DIR, then it'd be `target=${DIR%/}`

Comment: A link is dead ( Ukraine )

Answer (score 23):

Use `target=${1%/}`

See this [the parameter substitution of this bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) for more.

Answer (score 15):

I think better solution to canonize paths is `realpath $path` or with `-m` option if it doesn't exist. 
This solution automaticaly removes unnecessary slashes and adds pwd

Comment: realpath is not likely to be very portable: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101080/realpath-command-not-found

Comment: realpath is a part of GNU coreutils which is de facto in linux distribution and in this case users may have installed different external packages which can break the portability

Comment: Not every distro includes realpath.  For instance, I'm running Linux Mint 17 (which is Ubuntu based) and it doesn't have it by default.  It's in the repos, but it's not installed automatically.  That's what the link I posted was discussing.

Comment: Good solution for the specified use-case although the answer marked as correct is the best for the title and most generic. For me I wanted to remove the trailing slash from a URL so this would not have worked. Regarding your suggestion here, what I have found from experience is that `readlink -f` is a little more portable than `realpath`. For additonal/alternative options: http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink

Comment: This worked for me: `target=$(realpath -L --relative-base . $1)`

Answer (score 3):

Be careful, bash3 added perl-similar regex to bash. The guide mentioned covers this as well as the  [official guide at GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) , but not all references do.

#### What did I do?

Substitute `2.19/*` to be `2.19`.

#### Solution

```
VER="2.19/foo-bar"
NEWVER=${VER%/*}
```

Comment: Does not work, slash is still there (at the end of variable, which your example does not have).