# What is the simplest way to remove a trailing slash from each parameter?

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, rsync, stripslashes

What is the simplest way to remove a trailing slash from each parameter in the '$@' array, so that `rsync` copies  the directories by name?

```
rsync -a --exclude='*~' "$@" "$dir"
```

---

*The title has been changed for clarification. To understand the comments and answer about multiple trailing slashes see the edit history.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove slash from the end of a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848415/remove-slash-from-the-end-of-a-variable)

Comment: Those who don't know, in bash `a//b` is same as `a/b`. So in some cases one don't have to remove the trailing slash.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

You can use the `${parameter%word}` expansion that is detailed [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).  Here is a simple test script that demonstrates the behavior:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Call this as:
#   ./test.sh one/ two/ three/ 
#
# Output:
#  one two three

echo ${@%/}
```

Comment: +1: To be highly pedantic, that will remove a single slash, not all trailing slashes. To remove any number of trailing slashes: `shopt -s extglob; echo "${@%%+(/)}"`

Comment: Warning: you may not want to remove trailing slashes in all cases.  If "/" is supplied as an argument, removing the trailing slash will have ...unfortunate consequences.

Comment: PROTIP: Combine `tr -s /` with variable regex to remove repeated slashes then remove trailing slash. e.g. `DIR=$(echo //some///badly/written///dir////// | tr -s /); DIR=${DIR%/}`

Comment: @Dave Why spawn an external `tr` when it can be done entirely within the shell, as shown by @glennjackman above? Never mind that the OP didn't ask to have strings of `/` characters squashed from earlier parts of the string...

Comment: @twalberg tr removes ANY repeated slashes. glennjackman example only removes TRAILING slashes. Also, I'm not sure that it is POSIX compliant. My example is POSIX compliant and does more cleanup. It was just a related thought. Doesn't answer the OP question directly.

Comment: @Dave Exactly. The OP did not ask to remove ANY repeated slashes. Just trailing ones...

Comment: @glennjackman looks nice, but doe not do ANYTHING. `string_in == string_out`

Comment: Really? At a bash prompt, run `set -- one///// two// three four/; shopt -s extglob; echo "${@%%+(/)}"` and tell me what you see

Comment: @twalberg I appreciate "protips" that aren't just alternative answers to OP's question in comment threads.

Comment: I'd say a separate script is overkill, see @Ivan's answer.

Comment: @einpoklum, it's in a "separate script" so that OP (or anyone) can easily just copy/paste it to test locally.

Comment: Worrying about whether "tr" is spawned as a subprocess indicates that shell is not the correct solution for a problem (unless one is answering a twisty question for the Computer Bowl). Reading clarity trumps everything in 2010+ (insofar as that can even be had in sh/bash, stuff's is badly entropic with backwards compatibility)

Comment: Nice and simple, BUT BEWARE: it breaks on arguments containing spaces! (at least if used in the way the OP intended).

Comment: rtFolderin=$1
rtFolder=${$rtFolderin%%+(/)} does not work for shell argument

Comment: Corollary question : how to make it work within a script ? It is working with parameter $@ but what about a simple variable ? 
Example :
`x="one/ two/ three/"; echo ${x%/}`
Outputs : "one/ two/ three".
I tried to convert to an array but got the same result.

Answer (score 62):

The accepted answer will trim ONE trailing slash.

One way to trim multiple trailing slashes is like this:

```
VALUE=/looks/like/a/path///

TRIMMED=$(echo "$VALUE" | sed 's:/*$::')

echo "$VALUE" "$TRIMMED"
```

Which outputs:

```
/looks/like/a/path/// /looks/like/a/path
```

Comment: Don't forget to quote your variables, in case they contain whitespace:

`TRIMMED=$(echo "$VALUE" | sed 's:/*$::')`

Comment: Actually that isn't necessary inside the `$()` construct. However it is also harmless :)  so it's probably a good practice to use double quotes like `"$VALUE"` so you don't have to decide when to and when not to use the double quotes.

Comment: Any way to combine this with an earlier capture?  I want to strip protocol and (if present) trailing slash from a URL but `echo "https://www.example.com/foo/" | sed -e 's|https*://\(.*\)/*$|\1|'` doesn't work (since the capture group matches the trailing slash as well i guess).  I can do it with two commands: `echo "https://www.example.com/foo/" | sed -e 's|https*://\(.*\)$|\1|' -e 's|/*$||'` but wondered if it could be done with one?

Comment: This answer worked better for me with a very big input file. A simple `sed 's:/*$::' < in.txt > out.txt` does the job in seconds

Answer (score 40):

This works for me: `${VAR%%+(/)}`

As described here http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern

May need to set the shell option extglob. I can't see it enabled for me but it still works

Comment: To query a setting: `shopt extglob` with no options

Comment: This is Extended Pattern Language and you **must** set `extglob`.

Comment: This doesn't work on Mac OS X's builtin bash. The solution by Sean Bright above does: `${VAR%/}`

Comment: Pitfall coming from Perl and that realm of regex is that my instinct was to half forget working in globbing and pattern match, and instead try `${VAR%%/*}`, which deletes the first slash through the end (e.g. "foo///bar/foobar" becomes "foo"). *P.S. Surprisingly, extglob is on by default in Fedora 36.*

Answer (score 38):

`realpath` resolves given path. Among other things it also removes trailing slashes. Use `-s` to prevent following simlinks

```
DIR=/tmp/a///
echo $(realpath -s $DIR)
# output: /tmp/a
```

Comment: It requires all nodes in the path except for the last one to exist. If the user throws in some non-existence path, `realpath` shall fail.

Comment: @Livy `realpath --canonicalize-missing` works absolutely correctly with any non-existing part of path

Comment: and realpath is missing on some platforms :-(

Answer (score 11):

FYI, I added these two functions to my `.bash_profile` based on the answers found on SO. As Chris Johnson said, all answers using `${x%/}` remove only one slash, these functions will do what they say, hope this is useful.

```
rem_trailing_slash() {
    echo "$1" | sed 's/\/*$//g'
}

force_trailing_slash() {
    echo "$(rem_trailing_slash "$1")/"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In **zsh** you can use the `:a` modifier.

```
export DIRECTORY='/some//path/name//'

echo "${DIRECTORY:a}"

=> /some/path/name
```

This acts like `realpath` but doesn't fail with missing files/directories as argument.

Answer (score 1):

Approach I have used, when trimming directory arguments that are intended for `rsync`, here using `dirname` and `basename` to split the path and then recombining the parts without the trailing slash.

```sh
raw_dir=/a/b/c/
trim_dir=$(dirname "$raw_dir")"/"$(basename "$raw_dir")
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking note of a couple comments in the accepted answer:

1. Replace all repeated slashes `//[...]` with a single slash `/` (per @Dave comment)
2. Remove trailing slash unless it is also the leading slash (i.e., the root filepath `/`) (per @GordonDavisson comment)

```sh
trimSlash() { for s; do sed -E 's://*:/:g; s:(^/)?/*$:\1:' <<< "${s}"; done; }
```

Not as concise as the answers using parameter substitution, but I think its worth the diligence.

Some test cases:

```sh
$ trimSlash "/" "///" "a/" "a/a/" "a///a/" "a/a" "a///a" "a///" "/a/a/" "///a///"
/
/
a
a/a
a/a
a/a
a/a
a
/a/a
/a
```

Answer (score 0):

Completely POSIX compliant

```
# recursively remove trailing slashes
remove_slashes() {
    res="${1%/}"
    if [ "$1" = "$res" ]
    then echo "$res"
    else remove_slashes "$res"
    fi
}

# test:
remove_slashes a/b/
remove_slashes a/b////
remove_slashes ""
remove_slashes ///
remove_slashes ///a
```

Answer (score -1):

Not the most beautiful way, but quick and easy.

I just add a slash and remove all doubles. Assuming such a pattern will not be found elsewhere.

```
WORD="abc/"
WORD=$WORD'/'
WORD=`echo $WORD | sed s/'\/\/'/''/g`
echo $WORD
```