# how to remove specify characters at the end of string?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cut

I have some paths like so:

```
/dir
/dir//
/dir///
/path/to/dir
/path/to/dir/
/path/to/dir///
/path/to/dir/////////
```

I want to make it clearer using bash. I want to remove all `/` characters at the end of path and having:
`/path/to/dir` or `/dir` without `/` at the end.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus What I did is removing only one last `/` using `sed` command. So I need help in order to remove all `/` at the end of  string... So it could be quite difficult

Comment: @yasin, it is always good to add your efforts in your post as we all are here to learn, also try to mention all details in a single shot in your post. cheers and happy learning.

Comment: `sed 's|/*$||' file`

Comment: if you need to remove it from a bash variables, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/27846529 (requires extglob)

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a possible solution:

```
sed -e 's/[/]*$//g'
```

For instance:

```
echo '/path/to/dir/////////' | sed -e 's/[/]*$//g'
```

gives you:

```
/path/to/dir
```

Comment: @Lino, please use single quotes unless double is needed.. won't make a difference here, but it is a good practice to follow.. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables for details

Comment: Beware, `*` means zero or more, so this will always match in the regexp above. Perhaps `s/\/\+$//g` or `s#//*$##g` would be better.

Comment: @potong Could you show me exception of Lino's solution?

Comment: @yasin Lino's solution is correct but always substitutes even when there is nothing to substitute. This may lead to the wrong mindset especially at a later date when if the RHS of the substitution command is amended e.g. `<<<'/abc/xyz' sed 's/[/]*$/X/'` This also reminds me that `g` flag is superfluous since there is only one end of line!

Comment: Using / as the delimiter means you have to escape it in the regexp. just don't do that. `s:/*$::`.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '{sub(/\/+$/,"")} 1'  Input_file
```