# How to create files that should be named like the directories names in Linux?

Tags: linux

I want to create files and the names of these files should be like the names of directories in the `/` directory

I created a shell script like this :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cd /

declare -a array=($(ls -d */));

For i in "${array[@]}"; do
    touch $i
done
```

---

But it doesn't do anything when I execute it!
Although when I replace the `touch` with `echo`, it does print the directories names into the screen.
So I think the problem is with the `touch` command?

Or if there is another way of doing this instead of shell script?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [`find`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for this:

- Search all dirs `-type d`
- Limit to 1 folder deep `-maxdepth 1`
- Exec a command for each result `-exec sh -c ''`
- [Remove the trailing slash (`/`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018723/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-remove-a-trailing-slash-from-each-parameter)
- Run `touch`

---

```sh
find / -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec sh -c 'echo ${0#/} | xargs touch' '{}' \;
```

---

Gives the following folder on my MacOs:

```
$ ls -ltah
total 0
-rw-r--r--   1 me     wheel     0B May 20 11:19 cores
-rw-r--r--   1 me     wheel     0B May 20 11:19 Volumes
-rw-r--r--   1 me     wheel     0B May 20 11:19 dev
-rw-r--r--   1 me     wheel     0B May 20 11:19 opt
-rw-r--r--   1 me     wheel     0B May 20 11:19 Applications
-rw-r--r--   1 me     wheel     0B May 20 11:19 Users
-rw-r--r--   1 me     wheel     0B May 20 11:19 .vol
-rw-r--r--   1 me     wheel     0B May 20 11:19 private
-rw-r--r--   1 me     wheel     0B May 20 11:19 System
-rw-r--r--   1 me     wheel     0B May 20 11:19 Library
-rw-r--r--   1 me     wheel     0B May 20 11:19 sbin
-rw-r--r--   1 me     wheel     0B May 20 11:19 bin
-rw-r--r--   1 me     wheel     0B May 20 11:19 usr
drwxr-xr-x  15 me     wheel   480B May 20 11:19 .
drwxrwxrwt  16 root   wheel   512B May 20 11:09 ..
$
```