# Remove slash from end of chained grep and awk output, echo to console

Tags: bash, awk, grep, cut

Here is my input file:

```
/home/sites/default/files/Maple%20board02%2019%2013%20.pdf
/home/sites/default/files/paintgrade/side-view.jpg
/home/sites/default/files/paintgrade/steps_2.jpg
/home/sites/default/files/Front%20sill-photo1.gif
/home/sites/default/files/Rear%20steps%20Feb.%209.2011.pdf
```

Here is my grep/awk statement:

```
grep /files/ 404s.txt | awk -F '/' '{print $6"/"$7}'
```

The output from that statement is:

```
Maple%20board02%2019%2013%20.pdf/
paintgrade/side-view.jpg
paintgrade/steps_2.jpg
Front%20sill-photo1.gif/
Rear%20steps%20Feb.%209.2011.pdf/
```

(See the trailing slash?  Sometimes it's there, sometimes not.  Sometimes there isn't a subdirectory and my awk statement prints a "/" none-the-less.)

I saw on another post how to remove a trailing slash, but I am not sure how to apply it here.  The post said that `${1%/}` will give you a string without a trailing slash.  The post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848415/remove-slash-from-the-end-of-a-variable).  The highest voted answer is: `target=${1%/}`

I'd like to add something to my grep/awk statement to have the output be:

```
Maple%20board02%2019%2013%20.pdf
paintgrade/side-view.jpg
paintgrade/steps_2.jpg
Front%20sill-photo1.gif
Rear%20steps%20Feb.%209.2011.pdf
```

What can I add to my original statement to have the output be as above?  Maybe `cut` could help or my `awk` could be adjusted not to print a trailing "/"?

Comment: Are you trying to print everything that isn't `/home/sites/default/files/` from those paths? Because this is a circuitous way of doing that. And your problem is because sometimes the filename is field `$6` and sometimes it is field `$7`. When it is field `$7` you get no trailing slash. When it is field `$6` you get `filename/` because `$7` is empty.

Comment: Yes.  That should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove just that prefix something like this will work (substitute out the string and then use a truth-y pattern to get the default print action).

```
awk '{sub("^/home/sites/default/files/", "")}7'
```

If you need to remove X fields from the start of the line then using `cut` generally makes that simpler than `awk`.

```
cut -d/ -f6-
```

Comment: That's a new one for me, too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, if there is no `$7`, then a trailing slash appears.  Here is a quick solution:

```
$ grep /files/ 404s.txt | awk -F/ '{s=$6} NF==7 {s=s"/"$7} {print s}'
Maple%20board02%2019%2013%20.pdf
paintgrade/side-view.jpg
paintgrade/steps_2.jpg
Front%20sill-photo1.gif
Rear%20steps%20Feb.%209.2011.pdf
```

More generally, if there is the possibility that there are any deeper directories than `paintgrade`, then use:

```
$ grep /files/ 404s.txt | awk -F/ '{s=$6; for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) {s=s"/"$i}} {print s}'
```

Further, a separate `grep` process is unnecessary:

```
awk -F/ '!/\/files\//{next} {s=$6; for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) {s=s"/"$i}} {print s}' 404s.txt
```

#### A More General Yet Simpler Solution: use `sed`

This replaces both the `grep` and `awk` commands:

```
sed -n 's|.*/files/||p' 404s.txt
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer because it has introduced some awk descriptors that I haven't seen.  But, @Etan nailed it.  Thanks!